# Does Google-Collections work with GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, guava

I was just reading my news when I stumbled on [Google-Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) project.

Does this work with GWT?

Comment: why do you think it might not work?

Comment: Why shouldn’t it? And—more importantly—why don’t you just *try it*?

Comment: He wants to know if the objects are compatible and he's using StackOverflow to see if anyone else already knows. This is comparative advantage for programmers.

Comment: It's a perfectly fair question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the javadoc there are annotations for [GwtCompatible](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/GwtCompatible.html) and [GwtIncompatible](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/annotations/GwtIncompatible.html) so this suggests that it does work with GWT though not everything is supported.

Answer (score 9):

Google Collections 1.0 has the fruits of many, many hours of labor to provide GWT compatibility, but we were not able to get all the way there. So, the zip you download includes on GWT module. If you're very determined you can examine the build.xml file and try to build your own module and see what happens.

The Google Collections project will not evolve past version 1.0; instead, its entire contents have been merged into the [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) project, and it has already begun to evolve further under that umbrella.

We will strive to release a GWT module (or modules?) covering Guava later this quarter.